# Third Party JS not Working using require js Magento 2.3.2

Tags: requirejs, magento2.3.2, third-party-plugin

We are trying to create new Theme in Magento2. We have a problem in executing third party js file.

### requirejs-config.js file configuration

```
var config = {

  deps: [
    "js/default"
  ],
  paths: {
        'progress': 'js/progressively.min',
        'header': 'js/header',
    } ,
    shim: {
        'progress': {'deps': ['jquery'],'exports':'progressively'},
        'header': {'deps': ['jquery','progress']},
    }

};
```

I have downloaded the progreessively.min.js from the following Link
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/progressively

### header.js file

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'js/progressively.min'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    progressively.init({
        onLoadComplete: function() {
            console.log('All images loaded!');
        }
    });
});
```

We are loading the theme and content with no errors and there is also no error in console as well but js is not working. Can you please suggest us.

Comment: please check github link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1334 related to your question

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I have changes header.js file to below

### header.js

```
require([ 'jquery', 'progressively' ], function ($,progressively) { 
    "use strict";
    progressively.init(
        { onLoadComplete: function() {
            console.log('All images loaded!');
        }
    });
});
```